# SVG Circles do not register mouse events

Tags: javascript, svg

In the project I'm currently working on, I have a Voronoi diagram in the background, and I need a white circle with a single line of text in the upper-right-hand corner.

The circle needs to be clickable. Everything was going great, I have my voronoi cells reacting to clicks and styles as I wanted, including css3 transitions, when I realized that a simple `:hover` over my circle was not doing anything.

I tried messing the jquery `.on("click",...)` function to see if I could figure out what was up, but I still got nothing. The voronoi cells behind the circle were receiving the `:hover`, and the circle wasn't blocking it.

I then tried writing the svg by hand, to see if I just had some weird problem with my javascript.  Lo-and-behold, nothing changed.  I could get text and rects and paths to receive the `:hover`, but not the circle.

I am totally baffled by this. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/raphaeltm/zAYV8/) is a jsFiddle which demonstrates my problem.  I hope I'm just making a silly mistake.

At first I thought perhaps D3 was the issue (somehow), but after removing it, the code still doesn't run.

Comment: Your element "circle" has pointer-events: none;

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not know that property even existed. It seems I grabbed some code somewhere which had that included and I did not notice it.